# go generate invalid package name error issue

Tags: go

I have an application which is localized following the steps available [here](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/internationalization-i18n-go/). The simple application in the article works fine.

However, in my own application when I run go generate, I get the following error:

```
go: extracting github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae
go: extracting github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug v0.0.0-20180220043741-569c97477ae8
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/certchain.go:7:2: could not import github.com/pkg/errors (invalid package name: "")
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/ecdsa.go:11:2: could not import github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/internal/base64 (cannot find package "github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/internal/base64" in any of:
    /snap/go/4289/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/internal/base64 (from $GOROOT)
    /home/saraswat/go/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/internal/base64 (from $GOPATH))
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/ecdsa.go:12:2: could not import github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwa (cannot find package "github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwa" in any of:
    /snap/go/4289/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwa (from $GOROOT)
    /home/saraswat/go/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwa (from $GOPATH))
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/ecdsa.go:13:9: could not import github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug (cannot find package "github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug" in any of:
    /snap/go/4289/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug (from $GOROOT)
    /home/saraswat/go/src/github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug (from $GOPATH))
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/headers.go:304:5: undeclared name: pdebug
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/headers.go:305:8: undeclared name: pdebug
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx@v0.0.0-20180221005942-b7d4802280ae/jwk/headers.go:9:2: "github.com/lestrrat/go-pdebug" imported but not used
/home/saraswat/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20181114220301-adae6a3d119a/html/node.go:8:2: could not import golang.org/x/net/html/atom (cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/html/atom" in any of:
    /snap/go/4289/src/golang.org/x/net/html/atom (from $GOROOT)
    /home/saraswat/go/src/golang.org/x/net/html/atom (from $GOPATH))
/home/saraswat/go/src/bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/integrations/msteams/calendar/bottender_calendar_event_handler.go:18:2: could not import github.com/pkg/errors (invalid package name: "")
/home/saraswat/go/src/bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/integrations/msteams/calendar/bottender_calendar_event_handler.go:483:19: Config.CronScheduler undefined (type *config.Configuration has no field or method CronScheduler)
/home/saraswat/go/src/bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/integrations/msteams/calendar/bottender_calendar_event_handler.go:492:18: Config.CronScheduler undefined (type *config.Configuration has no field or method CronScheduler)
/home/saraswat/go/src/bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/app/app.go:200:9: Config.CronScheduler undefined (type *config.Configuration has no field or method CronScheduler)
gotext: extract failed: : : couldn't load packages due to errors: bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/integrations/msteams/calendar, bitbucket.org/thetalake/bottender/app, github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/jwk and 1 more
bottender.go:7: running "gotext": exit status 1
```

This same application and go generate run fine on two other machines. There must be a configuration error on my part but I don't know enough about go to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide tree of your GoPath and GoRoot? Three machines?

Comment: Have you run `go get ./...` to pull down all your dependencies?

Comment: @Frank Wang they are defaults. GOPATH="/home/saraswat/go". GOROOT="/snap/go/4301"

Comment: @Adrian this didn't help.

Comment: still not solved after 5 days? Can you provide your tree of GoPath, specifically github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx/internal/base64.

Comment: @FrankWang I am sorry but I didn't understand your question ( tried googling also ). How do you generate a tree of gopath? Thx

Comment: github.com/lestrrat/go-jwx have a directory internal/base64, your log said not found. Do this directory exist on your machine? use `tree ./snap/` to show tree of gopath.